# Laravel, error al ejecutar 'php artisan storage:link'

Tags: laravel

quiero crear el enlace simbolico en el `/public`:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Pero me dice el siguiente error:

```
   ErrorException  : symlink(): Operation not permitted

  at /var/www/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:252
    248|      */
    249|     public function link($target, $link)
    250|     {
    251|         if (! windows_os()) {
  > 252|             return symlink($target, $link);
    253|         }
    254|
    255|         $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    256|

  Exception trace:

  1   symlink("/var/www/myapp/storage/app/public", "/var/www/myapp/public/storage")
      /var/www/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:252

  2   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::link("/var/www/myapp/storage/app/public", "/var/www/myapp/public/storage")
      /var/www/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/StorageLinkCommand.php:35

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.

   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_mysql (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

  at Unknown:0
    1|

  Exception trace:

  1   {main}()
      /var/www/myapp/artisan:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Me tope con una solución de un hilo en ingles y te lo traduzco:

Asegurate de que la configuracion de `APP_URL` en tu archivo `.env` sea la correcta. Despues ejecuta los siguientes comandos en tu consola artisan:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan storage:link
```

Si eso no logra funcionar, te comparto el hilo en ingles, puedes probar con las demas respuestas:
[Storage in laravel says symlink - no such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409417/storage-in-laravel-says-symlink-no-such-file)